# Import examples for testing (Python)

Tags: python, testing, import

For the following problem I am unable to find an answer.
I have my program to do various stuff to graphs in one file. After my class definition and functions I have my basic structure of which functions to call on a pair of graphs.
Now I want to have different extra files with a pair of graphs in each to show different aspects of my program.
How do I get that file into my main program as if the code that is in the extra files was in my main program?
I know, it is a basic problem but I never dealt with this before.

For illustration:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(stuff)

    def plot(self):
        ...

    more stuff

# I want the following in an extra file #
# Two equal graphs

A = nx.Graph([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 7), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)])
B = nx.Graph([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 7), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)])
# That's it

x = foo(A, B)
x.plot
```

If I could also specify the file I want to load via command line, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your variable/graph pairs in their own python files and import them into your main file.

Ex.

example1.py

```
A = nx.Graph([...])
B = nx.Graph([...])
```

example2.py

```
A = nx.Graph([...])
B = nx.Graph([...])
```

main.py

```
import example1 as ex1
import example2 as ex2

class foo:
    ...

x = foo(ex1.A, ex2.B)
x.plot()
```

If you really want user to specify which graph pair to use at command line, take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

```
import argparse
import importlib
import foo

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example app')
parser.add_argument('input', nargs=1)
args = parse.parse_args()

mod = importlib.import_module(args.input)
x = foo(mod.A, mod.B)
x.plot()
```